# Encrypt all characters of the word by first parameter and shifting each character by the second parameter

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, for-loop

Input string will always be in uppercase. No need to shift any non-alpha characters.

Example :

```js
function encrypt(str, index) {
  var encryptedstr = '';
  var code = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  var k = str[i].charCodeAt(); 
    if (k >= 65 && k <= 90) {
       code = k + index;
       encryptedstr += String.fromCharCode(code);
    } else {
      encryptedstr += str[i];
    }

  }
 return encryptedstr;
}

console.log( encrypt('ABC', 4) );
```

but my code is statisfying for following instances

1.The return type should be a string.

2.encrypt("ABC", 4) Should equal to “EFG”

3.encrypt("AB C", 2) Should equal to “CD E”

4.encrypt("ABC DEF", 2) Should equal to “CDE FGH”

==========================================================================
but i am having following error

**The answer should be valid for any given input.**

any suggestion ??

Comment: Your code works fine for the scenarios you described, which test case is failing?

Comment: "The answer should be valid for any given input."  for this scenario..

Comment: @gurvinder372  I assume something like `encrypt('XYZ', 4) ` would fail :)

Comment: @vishnusaran give an example of scenario that is failing and its expected output.

Comment: @vishnusaran  To cope with any scenario, you will want to modulus the shift by 26..

Comment: So you want an arbitrary ceaser cipher

Comment: try -> `code = ((k + index - 65) % 26) + 65;`

Comment: yes it's working thanks mate

Comment: can you explain above piece of code @Keith

Comment: Yeah, sure I'll knock up an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,.

To cope with any scenario, you will need to cope with bounds, eg. when we get `Z`, shifting 1, should take us back to the begging,  eg.. `A`

So to do this we can use the modulus operator `%`, this basically is the remainder of a divide..

eg.  `10 % 3 = 1`, this is because 10 / 3 = 3⅓, so the remainder is 1..

So all we have to do is shift the characters back to 0, add our shift, then modulus this by 26, as there are 26 letters in the alphabet.  Then just add 65 back again, so our characters are starting at `A` again.

Final formula.. -> `code = ((k + index - 65) % 26) + 65;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you *could* do it for upper and lowercase ASCII.

but essentially for any character, get the character code find it base (uppercase ASCII is 65 which equals `A`) add the number of characters you want to rotate, mod 26 e.g. `X` -> 88 - 65 = 23 -> +4 = 27 -> 27 mod 26 = 1 -> 1 + 65 = 66 -> `B`

```js
const ceaser = (text, positions) => {
  return text.split('').map(ch => {
    let charCode = ch.charCodeAt(0)
    let base = 0;

    // ASCII A-Z
    if (charCode >= 65 && charCode <= 90) 
      base = 65;

    // ASCII a-z
    if (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122) 
      base = 97;

    if (base === 0) return ch;
    return String.fromCharCode((((charCode - base) + positions) % 26) + base);

  }).join('');
};

console.log(ceaser("Testing 123", 4));
console.log(ceaser("XYZ", 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle first part of alphabet letters ,last part of alphabet letters and non-alpha characters separately

Here is the code

```js
function encrypt(str, index) {
  var encryptedstr = ''
  var newAsciiNum = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
  asciiNum = str[i].charCodeAt();
    if( asciiNum>=65 && asciiNum < 91-index){
    newAsciiNum = asciiNum + index;//this is where the first past of alphabet letters are been handled
    }
    else if(asciiNum > 90-index && asciiNum < 90){
    newAsciiNum = asciiNum - 26 + index;//this is where last letters of alphabet are been handed
    }
    else{
    newAsciiNum = asciiNum; // this where the no-alpha characters are been handled
    }
  encryptedstr += String.fromCharCode(newAsciiNum);
  }
  return encryptedstr;
}

encrypt('ABC', 4);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please click on edit and add some words summarising how your code addresses the question, or perhaps explain how your answer differs from the previous answer/answers.

Comment: i think now its ok